# Validations of Model Serializers

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer, django-validation

I have to modify the feature of ModelSerializer, my expectations are as,

I have two fields in my Model. Both are charFields.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(blank=False,
                            null=False,
                            max_length=20)
    value = models.CharField(blank=True,
                             null=True,
                             max_length=20)
```

My serializer is as,

```
class MyModelSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    class Meta: 
        model = MyModel
        fields = '__all__'
```

I am have to create the object of MyModel using this serializer.

Now issue is that if I am passing the 'bool' values in my fields, its showing error message that 'Not a valid string.' (As expected by Modelserializer)

> {   "name":True,   "value":False }

My requirements are to handle the 'bool' value and converted that 'bool' into 'str'. what should be the trick to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

use the **to_internal_value** function, for example this works:

```
class MyModelSerializer(ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = MyModel
    fields = '__all__'

def to_internal_value(self, data):
    for field in ('name', 'value'):
        if field in data and isinstance(data[field], bool):
            data[field] = str(data[field])
    return super().to_internal_value(data)
```